# How does Capistrano work by default?

Tags: git, deployment, capistrano

Ok, before you downvote, hear me out... There are lots of walkthroughs online for deploying cakePHP/Wordpress/Drupal/Symfony via Capistrano and the projects own document is pretty good, but there's not a lot of coverage over what Capistrano actually *does* by default. Specifically, do a git checkout to folder `/timestamp`, `/most-recent-timestamp` to `/current`, webroot having previously been symlinked to `/current`.

I ask this question because we have a non-standard, hacked capistrano deploy process for a few legacy reasons and I'd like to bring us into alignment with the default behavior. In order to do so, I'd like background in what, exactly capistrano's default behavior actually *is*.

`cp -Ra /home/username/deploy/shared/./ /home/username/deploy/releases/20121026170156/`: this command takes forever to complete and I don't see anydocumentation of `/shared` being used this way: what is the typical role played by `/shared`?

Comment: You're asking several questions, and particularly the bit about `/shared` is in-specific and thus hard to given an answer that could help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While probably only the start to the answer, one of the best ways to understand any FOSS project [is via the source](https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano/).

Coming from the PHP world, you may be unfamiliar about how a Ruby Gem is composed.  Gems are made available to the system path [as an executable] by the presence of file in the `/bin` dir of the gem.  [Capistrano's is here](https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano/blob/master/bin/cap) - and from this you can see where begins the process of calling `cap production deploy`.

```
require 'capistrano/cli'
Capistrano::CLI.execute
```

In this case it loads the CLI library, and then calls a command therein.  Start there to trace what you need.

Comment: Thanks @NewAlexandria. Where can I find the CLI library?

Comment: [It's in the `lib/capistrano/` dir](https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano/blob/master/lib/capistrano/cli.rb), and then there is *also* a `lib/capistrano/cli/` dir that holds several files that you'll see required in `lib/capistrano/cli.rb`.  You may find it easy to look at a more0simple gem, [such a this one I wrote](https://github.com/NewAlexandria/morpheus).